# Find the joint CDF of the smallest and largest order statistics $Y_1$ and $Y_n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

**Question:** Find the joint cdf of $Y_1$ and $Y_n$ ($Y_1$ being the first order statistic and $Y_n$ being the maximum).

Find $P(Y_1 >u,Y_n ≤v)$  was given as a hint.

Comment: Any particular distribution?

Answer (score 3):

$\Pr(Y_1 >u\ \&\ Y_n ≤v)$ is the probability that **all** of the $n$ independent identically distributed observations are in the interval $(u,v].$ Since they're independent, this is just the $n$th power of the probability that one of them is in that interval. That probabilty is $F(v) - F(u).$